Lisp to Find Empty Closed Polylines in Autocad
I need a Lisp Routine to find in a set of selected closed polylines, the ones that are empty inside, im using Autocad 2021,
The information of the closed polylines using the LIST comand on them are the following:
Command: LIST
1 found
                  LWPOLYLINE  Layer: "MyLayer"
                            Space: Model space
                   Handle = 2c3
            Closed
    Constant width    0.0000
              area   300.5426
         perimeter   77.3595
          at point  X=4707.3509  Y=1402.3153  Z=   0.0000
          at point  X=4735.6706  Y=1402.3153  Z=   0.0000
          at point  X=4728.8578  Y=1412.4497  Z=   0.0000
          at point  X=4715.4995  Y=1414.5833  Z=   0.0000
          at point  X=4703.6106  Y=1412.9831  Z=   0.0000

My test drawing its in the following image, there are 2 closed polylines with a block inside and another empty, i need to select the 3 closed polylines and after the execution of the routine, select the one empty

I tried looking on forums of Autolisp, but only find Lisp to delete objects outside a closed polylines or something like that, i need the routine to generate the lisp document.

You'll need to construct a program which performs the following steps:

Obtain an initial selection set of all candidate polylines using ssget with the "X" mode string and an appropriate selection filter (reference).

Iterate over the selection using any method described here.

For each polyline, obtain the set of polyline vertices - you can do this using a 'massoc' function, as described here.

Perform a zoom to the extents of the polyline so that the next graphical selection will be accurate.

Attempt to obtain a window polygon selection using ssget with the "WP" mode string and the list of polyline vertices (and optionally a filter list to target objects on a target layer if appropriate).

Perform a zoom previous to restore the original zoom.

Ensure that any returned selection set does not contain the polyline currently being processed - remove it from the selection if so using ssdel.

If the resulting selection set is empty, the polyline is empty; else the polyline contains some objects and so should be discarded from the original set.


